# Unable to use a Nexus Docker Registry in a Docker Swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-registry, nexus

I am trying to set up a Nexus repository for use by a Docker Swarm.  However, I am seeing some weird behaviour and I am not sure if it is something I did or if it is a bug because it appears to be present since 3.12 (that's the first version that had the S3 blob store so that was the first time I used Nexus)

The behaviour I am seeing is `docker pull` works but when I do a `docker swarm deploy` it says the image could not be accessed. I don't have the issue with the `registry:2` image.

Here's the output from `docker pull` which shows it working successfully.  It also means that I have authenticated correctly.

```
$ sudo docker pull repo.devhaus.com/mylj-api:latest
latest: Pulling from mylj-api
Digest: sha256:e6ca3333cbe6d8c1761b2af2548610b068e1a268dac437598fb76a5b4102f9eb
Status: Downloaded newer image for repo.devhaus.com/mylj-api:latest
```

The `docker-compose.yml` file used for deployment is

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  apidoc:
     image: repo.devhaus.com/mylj-api
```

However, when I attempted to deploy I got

```
$ sudo docker stack deploy apidoc -c apidoc.yml --with-registry-auth --prune
Updating service apidoc_apidoc (id: odj2sgw8zugthjfk4jom1erms)
image repo.devhaus.com/mylj-api:latest could not be accessed on a registry to record
its digest. Each node will access repo.devhaus.com/mylj-api:latest independently,
possibly leading to different nodes running different
versions of the image.
```

I have also attempted to give the users `nx-admin` rights which they really shouldn't because all they need to do is read from the repository, not write.

In `/var/log/messages` the following appears on `docker stack deploy` but not in `docker pull`

```
Oct 17 01:25:59 ip-10-70-1-11 dockerd: time="2018-10-17T01:25:59.853065022Z" level=error msg="Handler for GET /v1.38/distribution/repo.devhaus.com/mylj-api:latest/json returned error: missing or empty Content-Length header"
```

I am thinking that `docker stack deploy` may be doing a `HEAD` request.

The following works:

```
curl --user XXXX:YYYY https://repo.devhaus.com/v2/mylj-api/manifests/latest
```

The following which is basically the `HEAD` request equivalent gives a 404 :

```
curl -I --user XXXX:YYYY https://repo.devhaus.com/v2/mylj-api/manifests/latest does not and gives a 404
```

I also confirmed that it was not a proxy issue as I hit the exposed port directly and yielded the same results as above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently it is a bug in Nexus since 3.2.0 since March 2017 (so it's over a year old) https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/NEXUS-12684 I guess we need to find an alternative repository system that supports Docker.

Or as a workaround for the time being, I created a simple proxy server that allows improperly built servers to support a `HEAD` request.  https://hub.docker.com/r/trajano/fakehead/